# Mensagem padrão para "fechar -> outro motivo" está em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

A mensagem padrão quando se escolhe "outro motivo" para se fechar uma pergunta está em inglês:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Lembro que ela já esteve em português, de modo que creio que tenha revertido pro inglês após alguma atualização na plataforma. Acompanhando a nova redação, sugiro:

> Estou votando para fechar essa pergunta como fora do escopo porque

Ou, se acharem que assim fica muito "abrasileirado", talvez substituir "Estou votando" por "Voto" ou "Votei".

Comment: "Votei para fechar essa pergunta como fora do escopo porque"